# Movies from property lists?

Tags: iphone, video, ipad, h.264, property-list

is it possible to play movies out of a property list? Like is there's a "tag" with the filename in it which gets replaced by the actual iphone/ipad player? The movies are h.265 codec...

thanks

Comment: i mean a "tag" which i can place in a string in a property list, like <movie>PATH</movie>, and when putting this into a UITextView, the device automatically turns this tag into a movie player to play that movie. u understand?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean, can you use the property list as an array which will hold a bunch of filenames for movies that you want to play?

All the property list can be is a text file of sorts that contains a bunch of key-value pairs.  I think you are misunderstanding what a property list file is.

Think about it this way: the info.plist file stores text data about your app when it runs or gets added to the AppStore.  That's all it does though: stores text data.  There are no special tricks like you're speaking of to get it to launch movies or anything else.  You'd have to implement all of that in code yourself based on what the plist value was for a particular key.